# Why does this line work without .value?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function check() {
  var input;
  input = document.getElementById("check_btwn");
  if (!input.checkValidity()) {
    document.getElementById("check_message").innerHTML = input.validationMessage;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("check_message").innerHTML = "OK";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="" id="check_btwn" min="100" max="300">
<button type="button" onclick="check()">check</button>
<p id="check_message"></p>
```

Why `.value` is not used in `input=document.getElementById("check_btwn");`
but it’s still working?

Comment: Because `checkValidity()` checks against the **element**, not against the value contained **within** the element.

Comment: Because there is no `String.prototype.checkValidity`. Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Methods), please.

Answer (score -1):

With innerHtml what you do is that you add any html within an id, for Ex.

```
<span id="Test"></span>
<script>
document.getElementById("Test").innerHtml = <h2>This is a test</h2>
</script>
```

As you can se the span tag will have inside it a new tag that will be an h2, with some text in it, now with value there is a difference, because what value does is that it changes the value attr of a tag, for Ex:

```
<input type="text" id="Test2" value=""/>

<script>
document.getElementById("Test2").value = "i am the new value"
</script>
```

you can also find a good documentation in 
[Javascript innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) 
[javascript value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: That is just wrong… you didn’t get the syntax and spelling right in your code, you didn’t address the actual question. IDs are irrelevant; no, the attribute is not changed; `Object.values` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @Xufox I didn't quite understand the question